# Oracle Reports Font Subsetting

Tags: oracle, pdf, fonts, report, subset

I have an Oracle Reports 10g rdf which uses an non-standard font which gets garbled when the client machine doesn't have the font installed. My clients machines are Windows-based in major and my server is Linux-based

I searched for information on the internet and stumbled on Font Subsetting configuration, which worked fine on my local machine, generating PDF files with the font incorporated. This PDF opened in all machines without problem.

I've done this steps on my server:

- I copied the font TTF file (inthrp48dmtt.ttf) to u01/app/oracle/product/10.1.2/frm10g/reports/templates
- In **uifont.ali** file, located at /u01/app/oracle/product/10.1.2/frm10g/guicommon/tk/admin/, i added:

  - At **[GLOBAL]** section

    - "IntHrP48DmTt" = inthrp48dmtt
  - At **[PDF:Subset]** section

    - inthrp48dmtt = "inthrp48dmtt.ttf"
- I installed the font inthrp48dmtt.ttf to the folder /usr/share/fonts/IntHrP48DmTt and executed the command **fc-cache /usr/share/fonts/IntHrP48DmTt/**
- Restarted the Reports Server

After all this steps, the font still garbled up. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Comment Global the section entry , `PDF:Subset` only will solve the problem.